# Sorting based on collapsed inner_hits

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, grouping

I have documents in elasticsearch, like this (each object is a separate document):

```json
{
    "name": "Steam Deck",
    "price": 100
},
{
    "name": "Steam Deck",
    "price": 800
},
{
    "name": "Nintendo Switch",
    "price": 200
},
{
    "name": "Nintendo Switch",
    "price": 700
},
{
    "name": "Playstation 5",
    "price": 500
},
{
    "name": "Playstation 5",
    "price": 1000
},
```

As you can see, the same products may have a bunch of records in elasticsearch, each of them with a different price.
I want to get a list of all products, with their cheapest price, sorted by that price in descending order. Here's the query I'm using:

```json
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "collapse": {
        "field": "name",
        "inner_hits": {
          "name": "cheapest",
          "size": 1,
          "sort": [
            {
              "price": {
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
    "sort": [
      {
        "price": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

The result I'm getting is (I removed some metadata fields):

```json
{
  "_shards": {
    ...
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4000,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "Playstation 5",
          "price": 1000
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "cheapest": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "Playstation 5",
                    "price": 500
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "Steam Deck",
          "price": 800
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "cheapest": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "Steam Deck",
                    "price": 100
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "name": "Nintendo Switch",
          "price": 700
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "cheapest": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "Nintendo Switch",
                    "price": 200
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, the results are in the order:

1. Playstation 5
2. Steam Deck
3. Nintendo Switch

Looking at the lowest prices of each product, the ordering should be:

1. Playstation 5
2. Nintendo Switch
3. Steam Deck

Is it possible to return results ordered by inner hits of collapsing?

Answer (score 0):

The top-level sort controls the overall results. So, I don't think you can have order by max price among min prices unless you will change your data structure to use nested documents for pricing, in which case you will be able to use sort mode and select min, max or average price.